# Get the last day of every month using static date in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, date

I have a static date eg month_end_date = 30/06/2022,

how can I get the last day of the month for each month from the month_end_date until next year 30/06/2023 in a dataframe column.

Just the last day of the month without creating an entire date range

Example output :

```
day
30
31
30
31
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with a month-end (`M`) frequency:

```
month_end_date = '30/06/2022'
stop = '30/06/2023'

pd.date_range(month_end_date, stop, freq='M')
```

output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-06-30', '2022-07-31', '2022-08-31', '2022-09-30',
               '2022-10-31', '2022-11-30', '2022-12-31', '2023-01-31',
               '2023-02-28', '2023-03-31', '2023-04-30', '2023-05-31',
               '2023-06-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

For only the days:

```
month_end_date = '30/06/2022'
stop = '30/06/2023'
pd.date_range(month_end_date, stop, freq='M').day
```

Output:

```
Int64Index([30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import timedelta    

month_end_date = pd.to_datetime('30/06/2022')
dates = pd.date_range(start=month_end_date, freq='m', end=month_end_date+timedelta(days=365))
```

Then create a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dates, columns=['date'])
```

If you want to add this column to existed dataframe:

```
df['date'] = dates
```